# how to get the table name from a sqlalchemy query

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've read through the query docs and don't see anywhere if there is a way to get the tablename from a query-- e.g. if I have `q = query(Users)`, can I get `Users` back out from `q`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that event simple query like yours may involve other table then Users too in case when they are related. So you'll need to iterate over it.

The following should do what you need [`.selectable.locate_all_froms()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.locate_all_froms):

```
for t in query.selectable.locate_all_froms():
    print repr(t)
    print "table name: %s " % t.name
```

Will result in something like that:

```
>>>Table('order', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', Integer(), table=<order>, primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=Sequence('order_seq', metadata=MetaData(bind=None))), Column('name', String(length=127), table=<order>), schema=None)
>>>table name: order
```

This should work for query build from Mapped object and also for query build from Table object.

Answer (score 0):

@vvladymyrov 's answer only worked for sqlalchemy v1.4

for v2.x use

```
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.sql import Join
froms = query.selectable.get_final_froms()
if isinstance(froms[0], Join):
    froms = froms[0]._from_objects
for t in froms:
    print(t.name)
```

Comment: Be wary of using private variables like `_from_objects`. It could be subject to change with future versions of `SQLAlchemy`